# Add an Option to Global Menu in Ubuntu 11.10

Tags: panel, top

Is there any way to add Logout option to Top Panel along with File Bookmarks View Go et al. ? clicking lefttop and then logout is quite a chore and i am lazy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since unity made it clear that applets will not be added to top panel (when unity was introduced), this might go complex just for the sake of laziness.

Other solutions are:

- adding log-out launcher to side-bar, although this might just use more space.
- adding a launcher on the desktop
- adding a keyboard shortcut (edit me if I'm wrong, but there's no logout button in Unity, no?), which would be the neatest and probably even easier solution than moving mouse.